# Couldn't create new record in the database with POST request

Tags: php, python, http

I'm writing small Python utility to use my RESTful API written in PHP. So far, everything works fine with `GET` requests, but when I try to do `POST` request, new records are not created in the database, even though response returns status code `200`.

```
from httplib2 import Http
import json

root_dir = 'http://restphp/restphp/public/api/'
not_finished = True

http_obj = Http()

def get(url):
    resp, content = http_obj.request(url)
    return resp, content

def post(url, data):
    resp, content = http_obj.request(
        uri     = url,
        method  = 'POST',
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
        body    = json.dumps(data)
    )
    return resp, content

# Code for getting data from input stream
# ...

data = {
    'first_name': first_name,
    'last_name': last_name,
    'email': address
}

resp, content = post(root_dir + 'customer/add', data)
print(resp)
```

This is the output:

```
{'date': 'Sun, 29 Oct 2017 19:27:29 GMT', 'server': 'Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.0.13 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3', 'x-powered-by': 'PHP/7.0.13', 'content-length': '109', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'status': '200'}
```

This is the route for creating new customer (I'm using [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/) framework). I checked API with [RestEasy extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resteasy/nojelkgnnpdmhpankkiikipkmhgafoch) for Chrome and everything works with it.

```
# Add new customer
$app->post('/api/customer/add', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
    $first_name = $request->getParam('first_name');
    $last_name  = $request->getParam('last_name');
    $phone      = $request->getParam('phone');
    $email      = $request->getParam('email');
    $address    = $request->getParam('address');
    $city       = $request->getParam('city');
    $state      = $request->getParam('state');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO customers (first_name, last_name, phone, email, address, city, state) VALUES 
    (:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, :address, :city, :state)";

    try {
        $db = new DB();
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":first_name", $first_name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":last_name", $last_name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":phone", $phone);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
        $stmt->bindParam(":address", $address);
        $stmt->bindParam(":city", $city);
        $stmt->bindParam(":state", $state);

        $stmt->execute();

        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Customer added."}}';
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error": {"text": ' . $e->getMessage() . '}}';
    }
});
```

I get random errors on every execution, like `'first_name' column can't be null` (even though whole data is sent) or `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`.

Answer (score 0):

When you POST data that data is sent in the body. Try this

```
$value = json_decode($request->getBody());
$first_name = $value->first_name
$last_name  = $value->last_name
$phone      = $value->phone
$email      = $value->email
$address    = $value->address
$city       = $value->city
$state      = $value->state
```

Comment: When I do `var_dump` on `$value`, I get `NULL`.